# Fire method to fill detailsview control, from jquery autocomplete input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have an input box for searching employee info (attached to a jquery autocomplete), and a box for employee number. The employee info queries multiple values (Lastname Firstname, Title, Clocknum) and returns them all as a string via the autocomplete. This is only if they dont know the clock number. The additional box is so they can search via clocknum as well.

Is there a way, to fire a method which populates a data control after clicking on or tabbing on the selected jquery autocomplete value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the `select` property of your autocomplete box:

**updated after ekoz's comment**

```
$('#lastName').autocomplete
({
   source   : "FormAutoComplete.ashx",
   minChars : 3,
   width    : 325,
   mustMatch: true,
   select   : function()
   {
      //jquery allows you to save several code lines
      $('#txtClock').value(ui.item.value.substr(ui.item.value.length-5));
   }
});
```

a complete read of jquery autocomplete's documentation should makes clear the code above http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: If I have the autocomplete pulling from a handler, how would I also use the select:? I have this so far `            $("#lastName").autocomplete("FormAutoComplete.ashx", {
                width: 325,
                mustmatch: true,
                minChars: 3
            })
            ({
                select: function() {
                    var empName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
                    var clockLength = ((empName.length) - 5);
                    var clock = empName.substr(clockLength);
                    document.getElementById("txtClock").value = clock;`

Comment: i think i figured out what you are looking for, i'm going to update my answer

Comment: Works great! Thank you! I wasn't using the jqueryUI autocomplete (sorry, this is my first dive into jquery) this works fantastic.